# remove leading zeros in alphanumeric string in java

Tags: java

My requirement is:

```
000000030899039 --> 30899039,
0-200IT-700 --> 0-200IT-700,
01-200IT-600 --> 1-200IT-600,
000-200IT-700 --> 0-200IT-700
```

Is there a way? Zero before "-" should not be removed/stripped.

Comment: What didi you try?

Comment: Alphanumeric is a combination of alphabetic and numeric characters. But your example seems to include `-` character. You need to clarify what you are trying to do. So does your string only contains `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, `0` to `9`, and `-`? And you want to remove leading `0`s excluding `0` preceded by `-`?

Comment: The string is with all combinations. I have to trim all leading zeros, except one zero followed by hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex:
`^0+(?!-)`
This matches 1 or more 0's at the start of a string. If a zero is followed by a dash, it doesn't count.

Since the last zero in `000-xxxx` is followed by a dash, it's kept.
You can test the regex at something like http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following (untested):

```
String str = "...";
int i;
for(i = 0; str.charAt(i) == '0'; i++) {}
str = str.substring(str.charAt(i) == '-' ? i - 1 : i);
```

Comment: No brackets, the semicolon ends the loop. You could also say "for(…) {}"

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of regex :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

//      String numbersWithZeros = "00000003089903";
//      String numbersWithZeros = "000-200IT-700";
//      String numbersWithZeros = "01-200IT-600";
        String numbersWithZeros = "000-200IT-700";
        String numbersWithoutZeros = numbersWithZeros.replaceAll("^0*(0-)|^0*", "$1");

        System.out.println(numbersWithoutZeros);
    }
```

output:

```
30899039
0-200IT-700
...
```

Comment: not working correctly. `000-200IT-700 --> 0-200IT-700` results in `-200IT-700 --> 0-200IT-700`

Comment: Here you go, Its all about regex, you should consider have a look deeper its very useful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "000000030899039";     // --> 30899039,
    String str2 = "0-200IT-700";         //--> 0-200IT-700,
    String str3 = "01-200IT-600";        //--> 1-200IT-600,
    String str4 = "000-200IT-700";       //--> 0-200IT-700
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str1.split("-")[0])+ (str1.indexOf('-')== -1 ?"":str1.substring(str1.indexOf('-'))));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str2.split("-")[0])+ (str2.indexOf('-')== -1 ?"":str2.substring(str2.indexOf('-'))));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str3.split("-")[0])+ (str3.indexOf('-')== -1 ?"":str3.substring(str3.indexOf('-'))));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str4.split("-")[0])+ (str4.indexOf('-')== -1 ?"":str4.substring(str4.indexOf('-'))));
}
```